# Duplicate MessageIDs on Google Cloud Pub / Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am getting duplicate MessageIDs on Google Cloud Pub / Sub. Do note that my payload aka the data field is the same during testing but this should ideally not result in duplicate MessageIDs. Please let me know what's wrong with my code below:

```
const publish = (topicName, payload) => {

    const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload));

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        pubsub
        .topic(topicName)
        .publisher()
        .publish(dataBuffer)
        .then(result => {
            const messageId = result[0];
            console.log(`${messageId} published`);
            resolve(messageId);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            reject(err);
        });

    });

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code conflates the publish call available in two different libraries. The `publish` call you are using comes from the [higher-performance Publisher library](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/0.17.x/Publisher#publish). In this library, you do not get back an array of results; you get back a single message ID. Therefore, when you do `messageId = result[0]`, you are getting the first character of the messageID. If you were to just print out all of `result`, you'd see that they are different for each publish call.

The array of results comes from the [PublisherClient publish method](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/0.17.x/v1.PublisherClient#publish). This method takes a raw `PublishRequest` and returns a list of responses, which is when you need to index the responses you get.

Comment: I used the code on official GCP documentation which seems to be incorrect. Thanks for the answer. Works now.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing out the error on the "Quickstart" page. I have created [a pull request](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/pull/108) to fix the docs.